# R studio wont recognize my variables? any ideas why?

Tags: r

So I imported the file and saved it as Purity and its clearly imported. I tried t-test but it doesn't recognize my variables. I tried using the names function to retrieve the variable names and its exactly what I'm entering, V1 and V2. I also tried with Lab-1 and Lab-2. I also tried just using dataset=Purity, all to no avail.

I took a screenshot so as to show code and that data is in the studio, can anyone tell me why this is not working?

[image]

apologies if this is painfully obvious I was only introduced to R for stats last week and am still a beginner, also don't have much experience with programming in general. I have looked at other similar problems but just cant see why mine aren't being recognised and others are.

Comment: What do you get if you type `ls()`?

Comment: just typing ls() i get character(0)

Comment: That means that nothing has been loaded into your environment.

Comment: Based on your screenshot, you need to specify your namespace- r only understands `V1` and `V2` as columns of the `Purity` dataframe, so you can't just call them by name. Try `t.test(Purity$V1, Purity$V2, paired = TRUE)`. The dollarsign is the standard way to refer to a column of a dataframe by name in r.

Comment: so in that screenshot, the fact that purity is in the upperbox doesn't mean I've successfully imported it?   I have managed to the test by reimporting it and selecting yes on header option so now V1 & V2 no longer appear then using code of Ceph-Bink.

Comment: Your screen shot reviles that you didn't set `header = TRUE` while importing your file and thus your header are part of the columns now. This means that your columns aren't numeric anymore and `t.test` won't work. You need to make sure that `Lab-1` and `Lab-2` will be the headers while importing.

Answer (score 2):

You've got 2 issues here:

1). You don't show how you imported the dataset but you need to either remove the first row or (better) name the columns correctly. I'm assuming you imported the data with `read.table()`. If so, then include the argument `header = TRUE` when you import the data.

2). You need to tell R where you want it to get `Lab-1` and `Lab-2` from.

```
with(Purity, t.test(Lab-1, Lab-2, paired = TRUE))
```

Comment: Man, you really need to change your avatar. That thing is even uglier than me.

Comment: @DavidArenburg, as someone near the Mediterranean, you should certainly have a better appreciation for octopuses. :p

Comment: I imported the dataset in tools->import dataset-> From text file .  What do you mean by "(better) name the columns correctly" ? as in go and edit the file or when I'm in Rstudio? I was given the data as part of class assignment to learn how to use R so didnt construct it myself. So I should edit the file or can I rename it while in rstudio?  The names function returns V1 and V2 so does this so not show that it does recognize these as two variables in the data?

Answer (score 0):

r is case sensitive. It looks like your script is using a lowercase 'v" when its an upper case "V" in your variable names.

The problem is in the way you have named your variable.  r doesn't recognise the hyphen (-) as a legitimate part of a variable name.  Try using underscore (_) instead.